# putting a vertical bootstrap button on the left edge

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to put a vertical bootstrap button on the left edge of the screen. Right now I have this CSS:

```css
#button1 {
  position: absolute !important;
  z-index: 10 !important;
  left: 0px !important;
  bottom: 20% !important;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<button id="button1" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger">Click to toggle popover</button>
```

The problem is that it's not all the way at the left side; it would be if it wasn't rotated but since it is, there is a gap of space. How do I fix this?

Comment: add html too to help us understand

Comment: added. Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: @RakibulIslam and one of your solution is copy of my answer. Didn't you checked before updating this 2nd solution? or just copied mine one?

Comment: SO is not just about earning reputation points by updating/coping answer. It is for education purpose for future questions.

Comment: @vaishalikapadia sorry, that was edited to provide comparison to both of the ways that can be achieved...okay, you're credited...is it OK now??

Comment: yeah. completely fine. Thanks. It's not about credit but about purpose of this site. :)

Comment: @vaishalikapadia No Problem, it was my mistake :)

Comment: please accept any answer if it helped you. By accepting an answer you verify that this solved your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `transform-origin: bottom left;` to your button

```css
#button1 {
  position: absolute !important;
  z-index: 10 !important;
  left: 0px !important;
  bottom: 20% !important;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: bottom left;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<button id="button1" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger">Click to toggle popover</button>
```

Hope this helps :)

> To learn more about `transform-origin` property, visit
>   https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform-origin.asp

Answer (score 1):

You can keep your button inside a `span` and set `width` of the `span` manually to stick it to the left of the screen. Here's the working code:

```css
#button1 {
  position: absolute !important;
  z-index: 10 !important;
  left: 0px !important;
  bottom: 35% !important;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  width: 45px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<span id="button1">
  <button class="btn btn-lg btn-danger">Click to toggle popover</button>
</span>
```